# File Downloading Error in ASP.NET - C# from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Kindly Look at the error screen. I just want to download file from template field in gridview I saving file in server directory and file path in db.

any with this fix or proper new solution

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
                onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <%--<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("filepath") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "FilesDownload"></asp:LinkButton>
                    --%>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="Download" 
                                Text='<%# Eval("Path") %>' CommandArgument='Eval("Path")'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>



protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "Download") 
            { Response.Clear(); Response.ContentType = "application/octectstream";
                Response.AppendHeader("content-dispositi­on", "filename=" + e.CommandArgument);

                Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/­File") + "//" + e.CommandArgument);
                Response.End(); }
        }
```

Comment: What's the value of `e.CommandArgument`

Comment: Try this Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/­File/") + e.CommandArgument);

Comment: yes this was the error argument not passing file path...all fixes Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the below steps:-

Add the TemplateField at the end as below.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("file") %>' runat="server" OnClick="DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and in Code-behind do something like this:-

```
protected void DownloadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filePath = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;
        System.Net.WebClient req = new System.Net.WebClient();
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearContent();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.Buffer = true;
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + Server.MapPath("~/YourFolder/" + filePath) + "\"");
        byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath("~/YourFolder/" + filePath));
        response.BinaryWrite(data);
        response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Reference link:- **http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-Files-from-GridView-using-LinkButton-Click-Event-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx**

Hope that helps

Comment: Your are love......<3 working fine as required...... can give you point due to newbie

Comment: what point do you want, kindly accept the answer if it helped you